# Effeciently test ifany three of four numbers are equal?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to determine a quick way to select sets of numbers (they'll be in arrays). I only need to keep sets where two or more of the numbers are greater than zero; therefore, sets that include zero three times can be discarded. I have come up with the following code but it doesn't have the expected outcomes, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
function testFour($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
  if(($a + $b + $c + $d) == ($a || $b || $c || $d)) {
      echo $a.", ".$b.", ".$c.", ".$d." => exclude<br>";
    } else {
      echo $a.", ".$b.", ".$c.", ".$d." => keep<br>";
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
testFour(0,0,0,5); // true
testFour(1,0,0,5); // false
testFour(0,4,2,0); // false
testFour(1,1,0,5); // false
testFour(0,2,0,0); // true
testFour(2,3,0,0); // false
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: just loop through the numbers and keep track of how many are greater than 0.

Comment: once you get to a count of 2 `return true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
function testFour($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
    $t = ($a == 0 ? 1 : 0) + ($b == 0 ? 1 : 0) + ($c == 0 ? 1 : 0) + ($d == 0 ? 1 : 0);
    return t < 3;
}
echo "<pre>";
echo "Test1: ".testFour(0,0,0,5)."\n"; // true
echo "Test2: ".testFour(1,0,0,5)."\n"; // false
echo "Test3: ".testFour(0,4,2,0)."\n"; // false
echo "Test4: ".testFour(1,1,0,5)."\n"; // false
echo "Test5: ".testFour(0,2,0,0)."\n"; // true
echo "Test6: ".testFour(2,3,0,0)."\n"; // false
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I've not seen this conditional notation in php before, what is it called? Also, could you explain how/why it works?

Comment: @Alex, it's called the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score -1):

The following will do as required for any number of values:

```
function testFour(...$bools) {
   $threshold = 3;
   return count($bools) - count(array_filter($bools)) >= $threshold;
}
```

This works because [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) determines if each array value is true through a callback, when no callback is supplied entries (after converting to `boolean`) will be removed.  Also the `...$bools` as the argument converts the individually passed arguments into an `array`.

You could also:

- calculate `$threshold` dynamically
- pass an an argument pass an `array` of values instead of each individually